# Ternary operator and void action

Tags: flutter, dart

What can I use in the second condition of ternary operator in case when nothing should happen?

```
ThemeModeHandler.of(context).themeMode == ThemeMode.system
        ? ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.light) : null;
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement.  You should use the ternary operator only when you need an *expression* (something that evaluates to a value).

Answer (score 0):

It is better practice to use `if` in this case

```
 
 
If (ThemeModeHandler.offf(context).themeMode == ThemeMode.system)
       ThemeModeHandler.of(context).saveThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
```